# Bounding the determinant of the Jacobian between a set and its polyhedral approximation

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sobolev-spaces, approximation-theory, jacobians, finite-element-method

My question is, essentially, suppose I have two simply connected subset of $R^n$, if I know that the boundary's of both are very close, how can I bound the determinant of the Jacobian between them. I can probably assume anything reasonable on $\Omega$, and possibly $\delta \Omega$.

More precisely:

Suppose I have a bounded simply connected set $\Omega \subset R^2$, with a boundary $\delta \Omega$ that is a smooth as I like. Think of $\Omega$ as some kind of distorted circle. $\delta \Omega$ is parametrised by $X : [0, 2 \pi ] \rightarrow \delta \Omega$.

Suppose I also have an approximation to this, given by $\Omega_h$ where $\Omega_h$ is a polyhedral shape. It has a boundary $\delta \Omega_h$ that is parametrised by $X_h : [0, 2 \pi ] \rightarrow \delta \Omega_h$.

Since $\Omega_h$ approximates $\Omega$, we have that $|| X - X_h ||^2_{L^2 [0, 2 \pi] } \leq C_1 h^2$, where $C_1$ is a positive constant and h is a small positive number that I control.

If I have a mapping $ \omega : \Omega_h \rightarrow \Omega $. Let $J$ be the determinant of the Jacobian of $\omega$. Are there any theorems that state something like:

$ || X_h - X ||^2_{L^2 [0, 2 \pi]} \leq C_1 h^2 \implies |J - 1|^2 \leq C_2 h^2 $,

where $C_2$ is once again a positive constant. Anything similar would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Perhaps my question is more about whether such an $\omega$ exists.

Comment: 1). What kind of bounds are you looking for   when you write $|J-1|$? $J$ is not constant: it depends on $x\in\Omega_h$. 2). I am inclined to believe that no such bounds exist because there exist many diffeomorphisms $\Omega\to\Omega$  that are the identity on $\partial \Omega$. (Take a smooth vector field on $\Omega$ that  vanishes on $\partial \Omega$. The flow of $X$ will generate many such diffeomorphisms.)

Comment: 1) Good point about $J$ not being constant, little oversight. I guess I mean something like $||J-1||^2){L^2 \Omega or \Omega_h} \leq C_2h^2$.
2) Also a good point. I guess my question is if there exists such a map $\omega$ such that the Jacobian has this property. 
I think it must be true, as if $\Omega$ and $\Omega_h$ are sufficiently close then the Jacobian will almost be the identity.

Answer (score 2):

First, since you are mapping a piecewise linear curve ($\partial\Omega_h$) onto a smooth one ($\partial\Omega$), a diffeomorphism $\omega: \Omega_h \rightarrow \Omega$ does not exist in the strong sense. What you want is a *piecewise differentiable homeomorphism*.

With that being said, as shown in [this paper](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masgat/PAPERS/EllRan12.pdf), Proposition 4.7, there exists a piecewise differentiable homeomorphism $\omega:\Omega_h \rightarrow \Omega$ that fulfils a second-order pointwise estimate

\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
\|\omega - Id\|_{L^\infty(\Omega_h)} \leq Ch^2,
\end{equation}

but its Jacobian fulfils only a first-order pointwise estimate

\begin{equation}
\tag{2}
\label{jacobian}
\|J - 1\|_{L^\infty(\Omega_h)} \leq Ch,
\end{equation}

where $J$ is the weak Jacobian, because $\omega$ is piecewise differentiable only. Estimate \eqref{jacobian} is optimal, so you cannot get a second-order pointwise estimate for the Jacobian. A quick way to see this is that you are mapping the piecewise linear curve $\partial\Omega_h$ onto the smooth one $\partial\Omega$, which is interpolation in disguise. Now, piecewise linear interpolation provides first-order accuracy for the gradients, only.

If you are happy with an $L^p$, $1\leq p <+\infty$ estimate instead of $L^\infty$ in \eqref{jacobian}, then you can even get arbitrarily good accuracy, i.e. for any $\varepsilon > 0$ you can choose $\omega$ sufficiently close to the identity such that

\begin{equation}
\tag{3}
\|J - 1\|_{L^p(\Omega_h)} \leq \varepsilon,
\end{equation}

as you correctly said in your comment.